# How to redirecting page if user directly entered page name in URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess, url

I have to redirect page if the user entered page name in URL. I have two pages called as index.php and shop.php

In index.php page there is a link called `<a href="shop.php?function=add">Click here</a>`. If i clicked on link then page is redirecting on shop.php properly.

Now the issue is if any user directly entered shop.php on URL then the page should be redirected on index.php page. That means the user will not able to access directly shop.php page.

I am not talking about `header('location')`

Comment: use [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to detect `GET` requests. for example, if `isset($_GET['function'])` then do something (show the page), else - `die()` or something (show an error, etc.)

Comment: why can't you use `header()` to redirect if `$_GET` is empty or doesn't validate? Also are you using a framework?

Comment: Mr.Charlietfl,  I tried if (!isset($_GET['function'])) {
 header("Location: index");
   exit;
} Page is also redirecting if any user entered shop.php but my link is not working. Means it is also redirecting on index.php page

Comment: Please clarify, what should happen if the user tries to access `shop.php?function=add`?

Comment: Mr.Abhijit, I have to run the add function from the link not to directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found my solution. I don't know my code is in the right format or not but my issue got resolved.

I change the link from this

```
<a href="shop.php?function=add">Click here</a>
to
<a href="shop.php?function=add&p_id=1">Click here</a>
```

and add below code in shop.php

```
if ( !($_GET['function']='add' && $_GET['p_id'])){
    header("Location: index.php");// send to login page
   exit;
}
```

Please suggest me if anything wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you should try something like:

```
if(isset($_GET['function']) && $_GET['function'] == 'add') {
    // Show page contents
}
else {
    header('location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Mr.bor32, I tried your code. but link is also redcting on index.php page

Comment: @NarendraVerma If you won't set `?function=add` to your url, you will go to the homepage. this isn't what you've tried to achieve?

Comment: But it should work. Do you always call the shop.php page with query "function=add" ?

Comment: Yes I have to always call the page shop.php?function='add'

Comment: What? `shop.php?function='add'` is not equal to `shop.php?function=add`...

Comment: Ehm. Please don't set the query-string into ' '. Just call: `shop.php?function=add`. `add` is not equal to `'add'`

Comment: Yes, Mr.natanel97 and Mr.or32, By mistake I added  ' '

Comment: @NarendraVerma please use `@` to tag us (but not on the same comment). you should not use `'` if you want to access `?function=add`

Answer (score 1):

You should try adding a random string to a session

```
 <?php 
 session_start();
$random = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
$_SESSION['random'] = $random;
 echo '<a href="shop.php?function=add&token='.$random.'">Click Here</a>';
?>
```

Then check by adding this to the top off shop.php

```
if(!isset($_GET['token']) || $_GET['token'] != $_SESSION['random']){
header('Location : index.php');
}
```

This way it will be impossible for the user to access the page directly

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_GET['function'])) {
    if($_GET['function'] == 'add'){
        // Show page if function is "add"
    }
    else {
      // "Function" is not "add", it can be anything else: "remove", "edit", etc.
    }
}
else {
    header('location: index.php');
    exit();
}
```

If you not want to use `header('location: index.php');`  you can use.

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location.href = 'index.php';
</script>
<?php
```

**OR**

```
$URL = 'index.php';
echo '<script type="text/javascript">document.location.href="' . $URL . '";</script>';
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=' . $URL . '">';
```

Comment: Really? `$_GET("function")`?

Comment: Mr.AdhershMNair. It will be $_GET ["function"]

Comment: Sorry Fixed it.Thanks.